# Java web application: start coding from a remote git repo in a debian VPS server

Tags: netbeans, debian, vps, projects-and-solutions

I have a VPS server, the OS is debian.

I have a ssh access to the server.

In debian I have a src folder containing a git repo of a java web application. The path of the git repo is /src/myRepo.

I want to start coding with a java IDE (netbeans?). What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem usually has nothing to do with Git.

Basically the workflow is:

1. Work on your project locally, build test.
2. Deploy the resulting JAR files to the VPS.
3. Re-test they work as intended on the VPS.

That is, in order to support this workflow,
on your VPS you need:

1. A working JRE.
2. A working web server — if you don't intend to host your Java application
   using something dedicated (like `tomcat`), otherwise you need that hosting
   application installed and configured.
3. A working SSH server.